# error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero (library modEvA)

Tags: r

I have seen that this is a common error when working with for loops BUT in my case, this error is produced when applying the function `modEvA::optiThresh()`. I guess this function is a loop on its own but I am struggling to solve my problem. The exact code is:

```
thresholds <- optiThresh(obs = mydata[, "observed"], 
                         pred = mydata[, "predicted"],
                         pch = 20)
```

but I get this error: Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero

and the object mydata is :

```
> mydata
   observed predicted
1         1     0.947
2         1     0.951
3         1     0.951
4         1     0.951
5         1     0.951
6         1     0.765
7         1     0.951
8         1     0.951
9         1     0.664
10        1     0.674
11        1     0.729
12        1     0.762
13        1     0.947
14        1     0.805
15        1     0.816
16        1     0.816
17        1     0.947
18        1     0.947
19        1     0.947
20        1     0.947
21        1     0.786
22        1     0.951
23        1     0.910
24        1     0.947
25        1     0.896
26        0     0.040
27        0     0.041
28        0     0.505
29        0     0.041
30        0     0.221
31        0     0.189
32        0     0.000
33        0     0.586
34        0     0.451
35        0     0.000
36        0     0.058
37        0     0.388
38        0     0.109
39        0     0.000
40        0     0.454
41        0     0.361
42        0     0.000
43        0     0.000
44        0     0.000
45        0     0.215
46        0     0.000
47        0     0.000
48        0     0.000
49        0     0.288
50        0     0.204
51        0     0.000
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just looking at the source code this seems really difficult to debug. The error message implies that `jj`, `iseq`, or `vjj` has no length, so it is either NULL or a base type with nothing in it. Try and step through the code with `browser()`

Answer (score 0):

Some metrics such as "OddsRatio" and "NMI" sometimes yield `NaN` of `Inf` values that can cause such errors. You can try it without those metrics:

```
thresholds <- optiThresh(obs = mydata[, "observed"],
pred = mydata[, "predicted"], pch = 20, measures = setdiff(modEvAmethods("threshMeasures"), c("OddsRatio", "NMI")))
```